# Map Tuples to Array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples, mapping

I have an array of tuples:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)]
```

What is the best way to convert this to just a single array of `[0, 1, 0, 1.....]` ?

I have tried

```
let newArray = tupleArray.map{$0.0, $0.1}
```

but it doesn't work and says consecutive statements must be separated by ;. There must be some clever way to reduce them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add both elements to an array in the closure and you also need to use `flatMap` instead of `map` to flatten out the nested array that `map` would produce.

```
let arrayOfTuples = [(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)]
let flattenedArray = arrayOfTuples.flatMap{ [$0.0, $0.1] }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be your answer :

```
let arrTouple = [(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)] 
let arr = arrTouple.flatMap{ [$0, $1] }

print(arr) // [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: I have compiled this code and i am getting same answer

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **`map(_:)`** and **`flatMap(_:)`** to flatten the `tuples` `array`,

```
let tuples = [(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)]
let arr = tuples.map({ [$0.0, $0.1] }).flatMap({ $0 })
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: That code simply outputs the original array and also produces a warning.

Comment: @DávidPásztor updated the answer. There was a copy paste mistake.